# Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I made the mistake of answering the query by Facebook about books I had read, and clicked that I had read certain books, when I don't in fact want that at all, because some of the books I had liked were pages I had created, and the "Books Read" section keeps linking to random wikipedia pages with no front cover graphic, and I'm OCD and it bugs the crap out of me.

Anyway.

My problem is that I tried to go and Delete Individual Stories on all the books I added to my "Books Read" section.  I succeeded.  Unfortunately, before I figured out how to do that, I hid individual stories, which was me having read two books, and now that the stories are hidden, I can't find them to delete them.  I tried showing hidden stories, and it didn't work.  I don't know if I've explained this in anything like a coherent manner, but I want to remove two books from the "Books Read" section of my Facebook page, and that activity has been hidden.

Ideas, anyone?